# Refresh periodically server data without page refreshing

Tags: html, mysql, ajax

This is the issue. I am making social networking website and I want to display online/offline user status without refreshing page. I have everything done in Mysql, online status is displayed on page, but without refreshing page changes in online status are not registered. So basically I supose that it could be solved with AJAX request. I want to get changes in mysql query and to display it directly on page without page refreshing.

Comment: So... go and do it? As someone recently said, this is a programming Q&A site not a wishing well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of different options, but two that I will highlight:

1) jQuery.  Straightforward JavaScript *library* way to asynchronously access the user data as you specify.  AJAX calls are built in by design.  See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.  This is pretty much out of the box functionality, and easier to implement if you're crunched for time.

2) If you're totally new to getting back end data into the front end, and refreshing on the fly, I might suggest you choose a more recently designed JavaScript *framework*, such as [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).  This would give structure to the front end of your application.  The only real drawbacks for this are learning curve (higher than jQuery) and SEO, as it is a fully JavaScript-driven output.  For SEO, there is a well-known workaround: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html.

Hope this high level overview helps put you on the right track...

Comment: Problem is solved with AJAX request, Thank's a lot. :)